# Use entire scope as input in plugin in Sublime Text 2

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublimetext2

One of the nice things about Textmate was the ability to pipe the contents of an entire scope into a command, like so:

[image: Textmate screenshot]

You could then specify the scope to be used, such as `meta.class.python` or whatever.

I'm trying to write a small plugin that will pipe the entire current scope in as the input for the plugin (for example (not exactly what I'm trying to do, but close), a function that lets you comment out an entire Python class without selecting it all)

Using the current selection(s) as input is quite easy:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin
import re

class DoStuffWithSelection(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        for region in self.view.sel():
            if not region.empty():
                changed = region  # Do something to the selection
                self.view.replace(edit, region, changed)  # Replace the selection
```

I've scoured the Sublime Text plugin API for some way to do something like `for region in self.view.scope()`, but without success.

Is there a way, then, to use the contents of the current scope under the cursor as input for a plugin function? Or, even better, a way to use the entire scope if there isn't a selection, but use the selection if there is one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get text that you select, the following code snippet is an example.

```
if not region.empty():
    selectText = self.view.substr(region)
    ...
```

If you want to get text where the cursor is located, the following code snippet is an example.

```
if region.empty():
    lineRegion = self.view.line(region)
    lineText = self.view.substr(lineRegion)
    ...
```

To get more information, see http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/python-tutorials/how-to-create-a-sublime-text-2-plugin/ and http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/api-reference.

Comment: Using the `if region.empty()` example successfully gets the entire line where the cursor is, but it won't get the entire scope. It also won't let you specify which scope you want (for example, a Python class has `source.python` `meta.class.python` and `entity.name.type.class.python` as scopes, with no way to choose which one the plugin will use.